# Load multiple images from specific pointer Id using iOS

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I want load all image uisng one id that is pointer.I have 3 class that name is "categories","Ads" and "adimages".The image of class is as.
[image: Adimges]
[[image]][2[[image]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnqUh.png)

I try to implement but can not get any succes.My implement code in xcode is like below

```
     var DetaiId : AnyObject = ""

   let query = PFQuery(className:"adImages")

         query.whereKey("adIMG", equalTo:DetaiId)
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {

                self.ImagearrCate = objects!
                self.getImageData(objects! as [PFObject])
                print(self.ImagearrCate)
                //MBProgressHUD.hideAllHUDsForView(self.view, animated: true)
            }
            else {
                print("Error")
                print("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo)")
            }
        }
     func getImageData(objects: [PFObject]) {
        for object in objects {

            let thumbNail = object["image"] as! PFFile
            print(thumbNail)
              thumbNail.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if (error == nil) {
                    let image = UIImage(data:imageData!)

                    //image object implementation
                    self.mixPhotoArray.append(image)
                    print(image)
                }
            }
        }//for - end
    }
```

Here Detailid is get the id from selected row of tableview.That id is passed in wherekey.I get all the image from selected row id.For example in adIMG column i 5 entry for mDjQTYaPMg id.Nut no any image find.

If try to put static id then logcat error is

> Error Domain=Parse Code=102 "pointer field adIMG needs a pointer value" UserInfo={code=102, temporary=0, error=pointer

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass pointer value as value of **adIMG** parameter means you have to create PFObject of **Ads** class with specific objectId.

Then you have to pass this object as value of **adIMG** parameter.

See following Code to better understand. May be help you.

```
let objectAds = PFObject(withoutDataWithClassName:"GameScore", objectId:"xWMyZ4YEGZ")
```

And then pass like this in PFQuery.

```
let query = PFQuery(className:"adImages")

query.whereKey("adIMG", equalTo:objectAds)
```

Comment: @tushar If helpful this answer then plz accept it .